# ServiceStack DTO Model Binding for Route Parameters AND Body

Tags: asp.net, rest, servicestack

I have a Request DTO set up for performing a PUT against a service that results in an update.

I require both route parameters AND a json payload to be sent as the PUT (this payload is the ApprovalRoleData object below, and represents the new state of the object I want to have reflected on the server):

```
[Route("/qms/{QAID}/reviewers/{RoleType}", "PUT")]
public class UpdateReviewer
{
    public string QAID { get; set; }
    public string RoleType { get; set; }

    public ApprovalRoleData UpdatedRoleData { get; set; }
}
```

Within my service, I have a Put() call that accepts this DTO:  The issue is that the ApprovalRoleData object is not being deserialized (but the QAID and RoleType are):

```
public object Put(UpdateReviewer request)
{
     string QAID = request.QAID;    //can see value
     string RT = request.RoleType;  //can see value

     ApprovalRoleData ard = request.UpdatedRoleData;  //null


}
```

Is there a way like in WebAPI to specify that I want model binding to work with both route parameters AND a body?

**Side Note:**

Also, getting the underlying stream so I can just parse myself with `base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().InputStream` didn't work since there was no remaining stream to read (i'm assuming the part of ServiceStack that does the model binding probably consumed the stream by the time I got to it?)

Comment: ServiceStack should populate your request object from Route and Body values. Route parameter having precedence over Body. How are you executing the PUT and what does your ApprovalRoleData class look like?